# ¿Cómo saber cuando una pista termina en el reproductor de windows media player

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Estoy usuando el control axwmplib.axwindowsmediaplayer en vb.net pero necesito saber qué evento o función uso para saber cuando termina la pista que se está reproduciendo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. La documentación dice [ésto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwmplib-axwindowsmediaplayer-playstatechange). ¿Te sirve? ¿Habías revisado la documentación oficial? Recuerda que hacerlo es honrar a los colegas caídos que sufrieron escribiendo esa documentación para que tú la uses :)

Answer (score 0):

En el Evento PlayState del Control WMP.Dll Te Muestra un 2 cuando se para... Cómo Tampoco Pones el Fragmento de Código de tu App, Yo Tampoco Te Muestro donde puede estar el error, pero ya te digo que el control WMP.Dll Tiene un Evento Llamado PlayState Que También Puedes Consutar Por Código el Estado, Pero Lo Mejor es Esperar el Evento Para Ejecutar Acciones en el Punto del Evento "PlayState" del Control...

Comment: será el evento PlayStateChange?